Is it a contempt of congress if somone refuses to give a simple answer to "Have you ever owned a business"?
The video here (tagged at 3:21) https://youtu.be/ARvCS8xwk8k?t=184 shows Rep. Lisa McClain (R-MI) questioning Acting Labor Secretary Julie Su during a House Education and Workforce Committee hearing. McClain repeatedly asks Su "Have you ever owned a business" to which Su responds with answer such as "my parents owned businesses".
I realize that this is a gotcha question, presumably if Su would have answered (truthfully?) no, then McClain would say something like "Well then how can you be in charge of this?". But this is a congressional hearing. How can Su get away with not answering the question? When I watched the hearings against Facebook or Google, and the members of congress asked vague questions such as if the companies could track the congressman (What does tracking mean? How accurate are we talking about? What if I can't directly, but I can infer? ...), it made sense that there was not simple yes/no answer. But in this case, it is very well defined if someone owned a business. When registering a business, someone has to be listed as an owner. If such a business existed, with Su being listed as an owner, then the answer would be yes, otherwise no.
How can Su get away with not answering that? Isn't that why the concept of contempt of congress exists in the first place?

Congress largely gets to define where they set the bar for contempt. If you look at precedent however, none seems to come down to this level of pettiness, i.e. refusing to answer a single question of that nature. Also

Following the refusal of a witness to produce documents or to testify, the committee is entitled to report a resolution of contempt to its parent chamber. A committee may also cite a person for contempt but not immediately report the resolution to the floor. In the case of subcommittees, they report the resolution of contempt to the full committee, which then has the option of rejecting it, accepting it but not reporting it to the floor, or accepting it and reporting it to the floor of the chamber for action. On the floor of the House or the Senate, the reported resolution is considered privileged and, if the resolution of contempt is passed, the chamber has several options to enforce its mandate.
Inherent contempt: Under this process, the procedure for holding a person in contempt involves only the chamber concerned. Following a contempt citation, the person cited is arrested by the Sergeant-at-Arms for the House or Senate, brought to the floor of the chamber, held to answer charges by the presiding officer, and then subjected to punishment as the chamber may dictate (usually imprisonment for punishment, imprisonment for coercion, or release from the contempt citation).
While Congress retains its "inherent contempt" authority and may exercise it at any time, this inherent contempt process was last used by the Senate in 1934 [...]
Statutory proceedings: Following a contempt citation, the presiding officer of the chamber is instructed to refer the matter to the U.S. Attorney for the District of Columbia; according to the law it is the duty of the U.S. Attorney to refer the matter to a grand jury for action. The criminal offense of contempt of Congress sets the penalty at not less than one month nor more than twelve months in jail and a fine of not more than $100,000 or less than $100.

So, yes, the aggrieved Representative could push for the House to follow contempt charges by either of those means, just for a single question, and if she gets the floor votes (see first para) then the contempt procedure would be followed,  but the precedent is rather against that, for that kind of question.
Sometimes what is or isn't contempt is hotly debated on the floor, and may go down along party lines. See e.g. the case of Lois Lerner. The Justice department then refused to pursue the charges (essentially claiming they were unconstitutional, given the precise nature of the controversy), despite the House passing a resolution finding Lerner in contempt. Yeah, the House could have chosen to exercise their inherent powers [instead of passing the case to the DOJ], but they chose not to, as it's been the case for the past 90 years or so. To quote NPR's summary of that, as it's more concise than Wikipedia's:

Here's the background: Lerner invoked her Fifth Amendment rights and refused to testify before the House Oversight and Government Reform Committee in March 2014. But Rep. Darrell Issa, R-Calif., who headed that panel, said at the time that Lerner had waived that right by making an opening statement at a May 2013 hearing in which she proclaimed her innocence in short opening remarks.
The House voted later in 2014 to hold Lerner in criminal contempt. [DA] Machen's office was examining the case — and, in the letter dated March 31, he disagreed with Issa's interpretation.
"Ms. Lerner did not waive her Fifth Amendment privilege by making general claims of innocence," his office said in a statement. "The Constitution would provide Ms. Lerner with an absolute defense if she were prosecuted for contempt."

To wit: I'm not claiming this case is quite like that one, since no 5th was invoked, but when pursuing contempt (via the statutory route) against administration officials, it's somewhat likely the DOJ won't follow through on what they perceive as insubstantial charges. The DOJ has also refused to pursue them when executive privilege was invoked.
Aside: in 2020 there was an attempt to revive the inherent contempt powers of the House, but that died in a committee.
Also, there's no 'double jeopardy' in contempt issues, in the sense that the House could use both the inherent and statutory route in the same case; they've actually done that once. A more interesting point there on the nature of the questions (when using the statutory route):

The statutory requirement that a question be pertinent is an essential
factor in prosecuting the witness for contempt. Pertinence will not be presumed. Bowers v. United States, 202 F.2d 447 (D.C. Cir. 1953). The right
of a witness to refuse to answer a nonpertinent question is not waived by
mere lack of assertion. The committee has a burden to explain to the witness
that a question is pertinent and that despite the witness’s objection, the committee demands an answer. Barenblatt v. United States, 252 F.2d 129 (D.C.
Cir. 1958), aff’d, 360 U.S. 109 (1959); Davis v. United States, 269 F.2d
357 (6th Cir. 1959), cert. denied, 361 U.S. 919 (1959).


Related Q on Law pertaining to other examples/refusals https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/what-is-the-statute-surrounding-refusal-to-answer-questions-in-a-congressional-h
